# No suitable JDBC driver found for HSQL db when adding JDBC jar at run time?

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, jar, hsqldb

I'm using JDBC jar for HSQL db at run time (i.e: it load the file path to this jar file from a setting file, instead of hard fix as Maven dependency). However, I cannot get the SQL connection to this HSQL db by adding JDBC jar at run time as before. Here is the code I use to load the JDBC jar file at run time for HSQL DB:

```
Connection connection;
try {
    // this is hard fix for example, ~/hsqldb-2.3.3.jar should be gotten from a setting file
    File jdbcJarFile = new File("~/hsqldb-2.3.3.jar");          
    URL urls[] = { jdbcJarFile.toURI().toURL() };
    URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls, DatabaseUtil.class.getClassLoader());
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
    loader.loadClass("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");

    // no error but nothing happens
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver", true, loader); 

    // throw exception because cannot find the driver for HSQL DB
    // with this url: jdbc:hsqldb:file://home/abc/hsqldb/test        
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(datasourceURL, datasourceUserName, datasourcePassword);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    //  (java.sql.SQLException) java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:file://home/abc/hsqldb/test
    throw new SQLException(ex);
}
```

I don't want to add this jar to classpath at compile time, only run time.

Comment: "I don't want to add this jar to classpath at compile time, only runtime". Ok, then set the scope in your pom to `runtime`. This seems like a roundabout way to do what you want.

Comment: @rmlan I want to load this jar from setting file, not in the POM.

Comment: I am curious what the value in that is. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @rmlan it is just the path to JDBC jar file, you can see example in the code "~/hsqldb-2.3.3.jar"

Comment: No, I get that, but I do not understand the value in loading the name of a jar file from a settings file. I think you are making this more difficult for yourself than necessary.

Comment: @rmlan because my database can be different DMBS, not only HSQL DB, so user can change the JDBC Driver from a setting file. Also some JDBC Driver is not free and user has to download manually first.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `DriverManager` does not allow your class to see this driver, because your class was not loaded by the hierarchy of class loaders that contains the HSQLDB driver.

Specifically, `DriverManager.getConnection` iterates all drivers, and calls a method `isDriverAllowed`, which ultimately checks if the driver could have been loaded from the class loader of the caller class, by calling `Class.forName` with the driver name, and checking if it returns the same class as the current driver. And this fails, as the driver class is not in the class loader of the caller class or any of its parents.

To get this to work, you would need to load the caller class using the same class loader as the driver (or a child of that class loader), or you'd need to hack the class loader hierarchy by loading the driver in the system classloader (which got considerably harder if not impossible in Java 9).

It might be simpler to just do something like:

```
Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver", true, loader).newInstance();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", datasourceUserName);
props.setProperty("password", datasourcePassword);
connection = driver.connect(datasourceURL, props);
```

Which means that you skip `DriverManager` altogether. I'm not sure if this could bite you down the line due to class loader issues, so I suggest you carefully test this.

Comment: I've found an easier way to get JDBC connection without using DriverManager, thanks for your detail answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

So I couldn't find a way to get JDBC connection at run time via DriverManager, but I can use DataSource to do that

```
 // Load JDBC jar from setting file normally
 File jdbcJarFile = new File(pathToJarFile);
 URL urls[] = jdbcJarFile.toURI().toURL();
 URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
 Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);

 // Create a javax.sql DataSource object (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder)
 DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().url("hsqlb_url").username("sa").password("").build();

 // Get a java.sql.Connection object
 Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

Comment: Which `DataSourceBuilder` are you using?

Comment: I'm using Spring frame work (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder)